# ColorBox doesn't like my Iframe Param

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to use colorbox to show some product details. The colorbox is being injected into the page from my c#. Directly below is the script that i got to work. it works but is a little buggy and my led dev suggested that i move it into a iframe.

```
 //ColorBox Scripts
        loadpage.AddExternalCSS("/Styles/colorbox.css", "colorbox");
        loadpage.AddExtJavascript("/Scripts/jquery.colorbox-min.js");
        loadpage.AddJavascript("$(document).ready(function () {$(\".imgProdGallery\").colorbox({maxWidth:\"850px\", maxHeight:\"100%\" });});");
```

The script below where i tried to add a iframe does not. When it is rendered to the page i am get the overlay with a very small empty white box. Iframe seems to be a expectable param why is it breaking my script when i add this?

```
 //ColorBox Scripts
        loadpage.AddExternalCSS("/Styles/colorbox.css", "colorbox");
        loadpage.AddExtJavascript("/Scripts/jquery.colorbox-min.js");
        loadpage.AddJavascript("$(document).ready(function () {$(\".imgProdGallery\").colorbox({iframe:true, maxWidth:\"850px\", maxHeight:\"100%\" });});");
```

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example5/ if you view the source it even shows the syntax where they used a iframe.

Any tips on things i could troubleshoot would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when using Iframe as a param for this you need to have a Height and Width declared. maxHeight and maxWidth do not count.